# Why is meta reputation the same as the main site reputation?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

If you compare the [meta users page](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users) with the [main site users page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users) you will see that the reputation is exactly the same for all pages. Shouldn't they be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [discussed](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28) on WebApps meta.